# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. [XAMPP server, WordPress Localhost]

Tags: windows, mariadb, xampp

I'm encountering an issue where MySQL consistently crashes with the error message "MySQL shutdown unexpectedly" every time I work on WordPress locally. This occurs specifically when I stop the server and then start it again. While I'm aware of a workaround to clear this error, it persists whenever I update or modify WordPress locally, leading to repetitive crashes upon server restart.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Set up a local WordPress development environment.
2. Perform various tasks such as updating plugins, themes, or modifying content.
3. Stop the local server ( XAMPP ).
4. Restart the server to resume work.

Expected behavior: The local MySQL server should restart without any issues and WordPress should function normally.

Actual behavior: Upon restarting the server, MySQL crashes with the error message "MySQL shutdown unexpectedly."

Workaround attempted: I've tried various solutions such as checking the MySQL error logs for clues, adjusting configuration settings, and restarting the entire development environment, but the issue persists.

Environment details:

- Operating System: Windows 11
- Local development environment: XAMPP
- WordPress version: 6.4.3

I'm seeking advice on how to troubleshoot and resolve this persistent issue to ensure smooth local development workflow without encountering MySQL crashes upon server restart. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Xampp ships with mariadb and not mysql. You need to check out mysql error logs and windows event log to get more information.